# java create a function that returns a hashset

Tags: java

```
         public static HashSet<String> FunctionName(String s, int num){
            HashSet<String> output = new HashSet<String>();

            /*
             * Code that adds elements to the hashset
             */

            return output; //this doesn't return/gives me a Compilation error 
          }
```

So how do I make it return the HashSet?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Looks correct. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: I get a Compilation error: error:" missing return statement
}  "                                                                
I use for-loops to continuously extract num amount of characters from the String s. Then I add what I extracted to the HashSet. Use the example s = "ABCDEFG" and num = 3

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, you cannot set a return inside an if statement, otherwise it ignores it and will still ask for a return statement.
*Note* This is only for returning HashSets. Possibly for other cases too.

Comment: Sure you can use ```return``` inside an ```if```,  and it will not be ignored. The point is that the return will only be executed if the if-condition evaluates to *true*, and you need to also return a value for when the if-condition is *false*.

Comment: Example: ```if (a == b) { return x; } return y;```  The ```return y``` is for the case when ```a != b```.

Comment: The statement was true, I just don't know why it doesn't return within the if-statement :/

Comment: (1) Your reported problem - *missing return statement* was a compiler error. You need to fix that before you have runnable code.  (2) Please post the code you're running so we can comment on it.

Comment: It did work, but for some reason it wants the return to be outside the if statement, because running the code without the if-statement worked fine, but I just didn't, and still don't, know why it only returns if its outside the if-statement.

Comment: If you posted the code, we might be able to see what's wrong with the code.